# Not able to override CSS within IFrame

Tags: css, iframe, disqus

I am using disqus comments for my jekyll blog with some CSS styles overriden in my stylesheet and used to work perfectly.

Recently, disqus has introduced a new UI for their comments system which has completely broken the font colors. Since my site has dark background, I am trying to apply styles based on new disqus HTML structure generated.

However, it seems that none of my styles get applied. It seems that is because disqus is loaded within iframe.

Any ideas how can I fix the font colors. Example of the post:
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2012/03/27/codeplexmovegit.html

**UPDATE**

Based on this question [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)
it seems that you cannot style a child IFrame cross domain.

I am wondering how it used to work earlier. Disqus even has documentation on it

http://docs.disqus.com/help/69/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried add !important after any css element you want to override?It has worked for me when I overrode the css div from twitter feed in iframe on my website.

Comment: Can you show me an example ? How does it work since cross domain it does not work.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja: For what i make it work, you need to use inline css on your header.An example of my working code is at http://www.stkildafestival.com.au and you can have a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bUDQ3/2/